# use asp.net literal and place holder for meta tag

Tags: asp.net, tags, literals, meta

I am trying to use literal and place holder to implement master page that allows adding meta tags such as description or keywords.  I am using following code.

```
Just for further info:
&quot; is used for double quotes
&#47; is slash (/)


<!-- description in master page -->
<asp:Literal ID="descriptionStart" runat="server" Text="<meta name=&quot;description&quot; content=&quot;test" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="metaDescription" runat="server" />
<asp:Literal ID="descriptionEnd" runat="server" Text="&quot; &#47;>"/>
<!-- end of description -->


In my content page I add description as follows:
<asp:Content ID="metaDescription" ContentPlaceHolderID="metaDescription" runat="server">
This is a test description
</asp:Content>


IE View code shows this:
<!-- description in master page -->
<meta name="description" content="

This is a test description

" />
<!-- end of description -->
```

It looks like ASP.Net is adding line break for lietrals.  Is it possible to show the description on the same line as meta description tag?

```
Based on one comment I received Alexander, I modified the code for master page.  It's enclosing placeholder in single quotes.
<!-- description -->
<meta name="description" content='<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="metaDescription" runat="server" />' />
<!-- end of description -->

Here is the output of IE view code after the change:
<!-- description -->
<meta name="description" content='This is a test description' />
<!-- end of description -->
```

Comment: Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you've added the line breaks, as your three controls each start on a new line. Put them all next to each other in one line, depending on your encoding that should do it.

I believe you don't need the Literals, have you tried to just write the opening and closing tags?